# Using “bindingRedirect” in app.config to redirect System.Net.Http references to a portable version

Tags: windows-phone-8, dll, portable-class-library

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 project which has a PCL project as its business layer. The business layer project is shared with the Android(Xamarin) project solution, and uses a HttpClient which we realized is not available in WP 8 projects.

So according to the blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx) we decided to go with the portable version of the `System.Net.Http v1.5.0.0` dll, which compiles fine with both the WP8 and Android solutions. But it gives an exception at runtime in the WP project

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   Insight.Business.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

In the PCL project I've also used `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and `Newtonsoft.Json` dlls which are dependent on the System.Net.Http dlls, and I think that is causing this exception.
I tried to redirect the references using app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.0.0" newVersion="1.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But I still can't resolve this. Please Help.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need binding redirects in the PCL or in a Windows Phone app.

Did you install the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package into the Windows Phone app project in addition to your PCL project?

Comment: Yeah, I have. Can that cause a problem??

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore Yes you should install the NuGet package in both projects.  Try deleting any binding redirects in the PCL and in the Windows Phone app.

Comment: That was what I originally did, but it didn't work. Can you pls tell me if the dependency of `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and `Newtonsoft.Json` on `System.Net.Http` doesn't causes the exception, so that we can take that out of the way??

Comment: Did this ever fix your problem? I am having the same issue.